# Let $T$ be the theory of linear, dense order, without minimum or maximum. Is $T\cup\{c_{i}<c_{j}\mid i<j\}$ complete?

Tags: model-theory

Let $T$
  be the theory of linear, dense order, without minimum or maximum in the language $\mathscr{L}$
 . Expend the language by adding it countable amount of constants: $\mathscr{L}^{*}=\mathscr{L}\cup\{c_{0},c_{1},c_{2},...\}$
  and let  $T^{*}=T\cup\{c_{i}<c_{j}\mid i<j\}$
 .

Prove that $T^{*}$
  is complete.

I already know that $T$
  is complete since $T$
  is $\aleph_{0}$
 -categorical. Two countable models of $T$
  are isomorphic.

Comment: You can show that $T^*$ is not $\aleph_0$-categorical (in one model the constants are bounded, in another they are not). So that direction won't work here.

Comment: I know. So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $T$ has quantifier elimination. Since we don't add any non-constant symbols, $T^*$ has it as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Hint in tomasz's answer is a good approach. Here's another one.

By Löwenheim-Skolem, it suffices to show that if $M$ and $N$ are countable models of $T^*$, then $M\equiv N$. Let $\varphi$ be an $L^*$-sentence. Then $\varphi$ is an $L'$-sentence, where $L'$ is a finite sublanguage of $L^*$ (in particular, it only has finitely many of the new constant symbols). Show that $M|_{L'}\cong N|_{L'}$.